# System.StackOverflowException was unhandled error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, repository

I am fairly new to repositories and mock repositories, so I would like help understanding what this error means exactly and how to avoid it. I have looked at other posts and done my research but they are too specific to their errors. 
The code that is breaking is

```
public int PersistComponentDb(Core.Models.ComponentDbModel componentDb)
{
    return PersistComponentDb(componentDb);
}
```

I understand that the function is calling itself but how do I stop it from doing that? It is persisting a mock repository, and the hard coded values look like this

```
public DataTable GetComponentDbs(int? forComponentId = null, int? forDbServerId = null, int? forEntityId = null)
{
    DataTable componentDbs = new DataTable();
    componentDbs.Columns.Add("ComponentDbID", typeof(Int32));
    componentDbs.Columns.Add("ComponentID", typeof(Int32));
    componentDbs.Columns.Add("DbServerID", typeof(Int32));
    componentDbs.Columns.Add("EntityID", typeof(int));
    componentDbs.Columns.Add("SecurableGuid", typeof(String));
    componentDbs.Columns.Add("FriendlyName", typeof(String));
    componentDbs.Columns.Add("DbName", typeof(String));
    componentDbs.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 2, 2, 3822, "SecureableGuid", "Test #1", "DB #1" });
    return componentDbs;
}

public DataRow GetComponentDb(int id)
{
    DataTable componentDbs = new DataTable();   
    componentDbs.Columns.Add("ComponentDbID", typeof(Int32));
    componentDbs.Columns.Add("ComponentID", typeof(Int32));
    componentDbs.Columns.Add("DbServerID", typeof(Int32));
    componentDbs.Columns.Add("EntityID", typeof(Int32));
    componentDbs.Columns.Add("SecurableGuid", typeof(String));
    componentDbs.Columns.Add("FriendlyName", typeof(String));
    componentDbs.Columns.Add("DbName", typeof(String));
    componentDbs.Rows.Add(new object[] { 123, 121, 12, null, "SecurableGuid", "Name", "Database name" });
    return componentDbs.Rows[0];
}
```

The rest of the code that is behind `PersistComponentDb` is

```
public int PersistComponentDb(ComponentDbModel componentDb)
{
    // Example implementation.
    return _repository.PersistComponentDb(componentDb);
}
```

and

`int PersistComponentDb(ComponentDbModel componentDb);`

Comment: @PrestonGuillot I'm guessing it's a typo and the `new` shouldn't be there.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot you are correct, I was trying it out right before I posted this. I have edited to what it is.

Comment: What is `PersistCompnentDB` suppose to do?  I'm not sure this should even be a recursive call, but if it is you need a base case and you should be breaking down the problem into similar sub problems.  So there should be at least one return that doesn't make a recursive call and the recursive call(s) should not be identical to the original call.

Comment: @juharr 'PersistComponentDB' is suppose to update and save into the "database", 'int PersistComponentDb(ComponentDbModel componentDb);' and ' public int PersistComponentDb(ComponentDbModel componentDb)
        {
            // Example implementation.
            return _repository.PersistComponentDb(componentDb);
        }' is the rest of the code that is behind 'PersistComponentDb'

Comment: Well `retrun _repository.PersistComponentDb(componentDb);` would work since that calls a similarly named method on a different object.  Do you have a variable called `_repository`?

Comment: @juharr I just created one, but now it is giving me a System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code error. Is that because I am persisting to a static hard coded method and not something that is dynamic?

Comment: No, that probably means you didn't initialize `_repository` to whatever it is suppose to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this method is calling itself. hence the stackoverflow.

```
public int PersistComponentDb(Core.Models.ComponentDbModel componentDb)
{
    return PersistComponentDb(componentDb);
}
```

should this code be:

```
public int PersistComponentDb(Core.Models.ComponentDbModel componentDb)
{
    return _repository.PersistComponentDb(componentDb);
}
```